# How to mock a internal object when doing unit test?

Tags: unit-testing

I've a class like this:

```
Class A 
{
   public boolean do(String s)
   {
        C c = DB.GetResult(s);
        ....
        return yes/no
   }
}
```

How I want to write unit test with Mockito, but How can I mock the internal object C to suppress the database connection operations.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to mock internal object DB not C right?

In code like you have you can't. You have to inject DB into class A. Then in unit tests you inject mock/stub instead of object that talks to database.

Edit:
You could do this (I'm using C#):

```
Class A 
{
   private readonly IDb database;

   // you can inject by hand or using IoC container
   // if you don't like that you have to pass IDb implementation everywhere
   // where you create objects of type A you can add another constructor - look under
   public A(IDb database)
   {
       this.database = database;
   }

   // here you call the above constructor and pass you original DB object
   public A() : this(new DB())
   {
   }

   public boolean do(String s)
   {
        C c = database.GetResult(s);
        ....
        return yes/no
   }
}
```

Of course your DB class has to implement IDb interface.

```
interface IDb
{
    C GetResults(String s);
}
```

Now in you tests you do this:

```
var a = new A(new TestDBDoingReturningExactlyWhatYouTellItToReturn());
```

and in application code:

```
var a = new A(new DB());
```

or parameterless constructor that does exactly what line above

```
var a = new A();
```

Comment: Mockito doesn't support class's static method. How can I inject DB and method ?

Comment: DB.GetResult cannot be static in order to mock it. Do you really need it to be static? There's really not that many reasons to make methods static.

Comment: I can change it to non-static. But a DB class appears inner method.DB db = new DB();  C c= db.get();   The same problem is coming. How can I mock db object?

Comment: Hi, Peri. Actually I test the map reduce class, and can not set some extra object as parameters to Mapper or Reducer. But fortunately, I resolve it by the ugly method. Extract some db operation codes to a public method, and mock this method in test case.